# Listbox RowSource not showing joined columns although query does

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query which works as it should in the Query-View in Access, but when I use the very same query for populating a list in a Form, the tables are not joined together.

The structure is very easy, the joined data are just brands and types.

The SQL-Code:

```
SELECT tblDBReifen.herst_fk, tblDBReifen.dbPROFIL AS Profil, tblDBReifen.rtyp_fk AS Reifentyp
FROM (tblDBReifen 
LEFT JOIN tblHersteller ON tblDBReifen.[herst_fk] = tblHersteller.[herst_id]) 
LEFT JOIN tblReifentyp ON tblDBReifen.[rtyp_fk] = tblReifentyp.[rtype_id];
```

VBA Code:

```
lstReifenauswahl.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
lstReifenauswahl.RowSource = "StringNameOfTheQuery"
```

When viewing the query in Access, I get the table right:

```
| Herst    | Profil       |    Typ     |
| Pirelli  | Somename     | Summer     |
| Michelin | Othername    | Winter     |
```

But the list in the form shows only the indexes:

```
| Herst    |   Profil     |    Typ     |
| 2        | Somename     | 1          |
| 4        | Othername    | 2          |
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are using _lookup fields_, so include table _Hersteller_ and _Type_ in your query and select the fields from these that holds the names of _Herst_ and _Typ_. Lookup fields may seem smart but will cause endless troubles like this.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Gustav, that was it. It also solved the problem I had with the column names as it seems that Access ignores the aliases on those columns.

Comment: Why did you include tblHersteller and tblReifentyp in query to begin with if you did not intend to use any fields from them? What did you think just joining would accomplish?

Comment: @June7 This is the SQL Statement that MS-Access _gives you_ when you make the Query with the Query-Assistant so I assumed that is how Access wants the query to look like, but apparently not.

Comment: By Query-Assistant you mean query designer or wizard ? I have never seen either include tables I did not request so I am still confused as to why your query had tables whose fields were not referenced.

Comment: Yes, I mean the designer. And now I see my mistake. Although the tables where there, I was clicking the whole time the foreign_key fields instead of the fields in the referenced tables... but it works, somehow. It shows the joined fields when testing the query, but not when using it...
Anyway, thanks for the hint, now I fully comprehend the error.